# Gimp, Custom page size for printing

Tags: printing, gimp, setup, page

Trouble setting up a new custom page size in gimp.

Found where it is to be done;
Menu: File > Print > opens a dialog with tabs for print destination and setup.

The /Page Setup\ tab has a "Paper size" drop down list.
There is a "Custom" selection - but that seems to be bogus (as in: should simply not be there).

How to create new page sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead for selecting "Custom" page size, look for "Manage Custom Sizes" a the far bottom of the drop down list.

This opens a dialog where you can manage the current custom page size settings.

[image: The Custom page size dialog]

Click the <kbd>+</kbd> to create a new size, type in a name for it and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> (Note <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will not work, just reset the name!) and the fill in the measurements.

Make sure to fill in the longer side as "Height" - as the settings here assumes the numbers are for portrait orientation (also note the use of `,` for decimal separation).

If the measurements should be in mm, inches are 25.4mm (=1" - 12.7, 6.35, 2.54, 1.27mm for 1/2", 1/4", 1/10" and 1/20").

Comment: This is valid for at least gimp 2.9.5 as of 2017-08-12